# Help finding a linear actuator

Tags: motor

I need help finding a linear actuator.

I only need it to move 15 mm but it also needs to move extremely fast. Preferably 1 inch per second. It needs to be capable of holding a 10 lb weight. The stroke speed is at full load. Also, I would greatly prefer it to be fairly cheap because I need to buy 4.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* MacusLittle, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61823/discussion-on-question-by-macus-little-help-finding-a-linear-actuator).